# Await a System.Threading.Task and ignore the result?

Tags: f#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to learn F# by diving straight in and attempting to convert some C# code to it. One of the things I'm rewriting is part of an async method, which awaits a call to HttpClient's GetAsync without using the result. That is:

```
await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.example.com");
```

Below is the only thing I've tried which doesn't get the red squigglies. While I assume it's valid, it does create a variable which I'd probably want to avoid.

```
let! ignoreme = Async.AwaitTask <| httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.example.com")
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `do!` operator combined with `Async.Ignore`:

```
do! Async.AwaitTask(httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.example.com")) |> Async.Ignore
```

This is the same as writing `let! ignoreme = ...` and then ignoring the `ignoreme` binding.

However I think it is better to stick with F# data types -- avoid `Async.AwaitTask` where you can and work directly with the `Async<'T>` type. I think the [FSharp.Data library](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) would be of good help.

Comment: I get "This expression was expected to have type `HttpResponseMessage` but here has type `unit`"

Comment: @unrelativity, yes, sorry about that. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Ah, that works! Thanks for linking to that library as well, it does seem best to work with libraries written with F# in mind.